# woocommerce dynamic pricing display discount table

Tags: woocommerce

I use the [woocommerce dynamic pricing plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/) by Lucas Stark, the problem is that it doesn't display the discounts which isn't great from a marketing perspective. The problem is highlighted well [here](http://chrislema.com/the-flaw-in-the-woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-extension/)

[This code](http://pastebin.com/mnFpKHCi), found in the Chris Lema link above, does display a discount table. BUT I use % discounts and [this code](http://pastebin.com/mnFpKHCi) doesn't work with that. e.g. a product's normal price is $100, 5% off if they buy more than 5, 10% off if they buy 10 or more, shows as price for 5 or more $5 10 or more $10. Clearly this isn't right it should display 5 or more $95 10 or more $90 - How do I achieve that?

Lastly from a marketing perspective it would be good if all products with a quantity discount displayed the cheapest price on the main price. e.g a product that is $100 normally, but with 5% off if you buy 5 or more or 10% off if you buy 10 or more should display the discount table as above but should also display from $90 i.e. the cheapest price, as the main price instead of $100 - How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

"...for performance reasons we decided that it should remain out" according to the plugin creator, Lucas.

I am thinking of a workaround like a  meta box in each post where you can type discount information in just plain text and then hook to woocommerce_price_html(which runs everytime the shop page and single product page is displayed), thus eliminating the need to tweak Lucas Stark's plugin.

Lucas also released a new [extension](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-conditional-content/)
( October 2013 ) which is purported to be  'a great way to let users know about a discount they can receive if they purchase more products.' This [user](http://chrislema.com/the-flaw-in-the-woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-extension/#comment-8267) said this extension has issues with discount tables, but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used either personally, but http://www.wplab.com/shop/woocommerce-bulk-pricing/ does bulk pricing with a display table if that's the killer feature.

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-discounts/6533113
It does allow to create discounts similar to what you need plus it displays discounts on both single and variable products .

try the demo here http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-discounts/full_screen_preview/6533113

Answer (score 0):

There are more alternatives that are capable of displaying a quantity pricing table. Like the one that james posted or [WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279).

Also, it would be possible to hire some freelancer that would make it work with the plugin that you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution - though it does not (currently) allow the filtering of pricing results based on user role....

http://blueskysessions.com/2014/03/31/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-plugin-how-to-show-the-quantity-pricing-rules-for-all-product-variations-on-the-product-page/#comments